# Notepad++ regex to remove words followed by more than one space

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using the replace functionality of notepad++, I would like to remove (replace by white space) all words in a text file that are followed by more than one white space. What would be the regular expression to do so?

For instance: `blabla    blabla1 blabla2 blabla3` should become `blabla1 blabla2 blabla3`

Comment: And you tried ... what did you try?

Comment: Your task is rather unclear without any insight into what problem you experienced when trying to achieve your goal. I can write an answer with several ways to do that, but in the end, they might turn out useless.

Comment: What is `word` for you?

Comment: Why do you accept an answer that does not do what you ask for?

Comment: It does what I asked for. In the notepad++ interface, for "find what" I put `\w+(?=\s{2,})`, and for "replace with" I put a whitespace. Works like a charm

Comment: @Antoine: No, you wrote you wanted `blabla1 blabla2 blabla3`, but you get the leading spaces before that string after the regex-based replacement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in that particular case it's fine either way, I don't mind

Comment: You should make that clear in the question. Otherwise, it is unclear. Moreover, you *should* provide what you have tried, otherwise it is off-topic. See [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/285739#285739) And believe me, if you did that, you would get a much better regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following .

```
\w+(?=\s{2,})
```

This [will match words](https://regex101.com/r/hT6pB5/1)  which you should replace.

Comment: Did OP provide any efforts? No. Do not do others' work. BTW, `\w+(?=\s{2,})` regex does not work as expected.

Comment: This still does not replace with a whitespace. The result is "  blabla1 blabla2 blabla3", and the expected result is `blabla1 blabla2 blabla3`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew are not they equal ? Expected and actual ?

Comment: Why not use `\w+\s{2,}`?

Comment: @slartidan  that will match white spaces too. and question was *all words in a text file that are followed by more than one white space* e.i only words.

Comment: @Antoine glad if helped.

Comment: @tchelidze True. But the example in the question also has white spaces removed. I'm not sure, what the desired behavior really is.

Comment: @slartidan Thank you for notice, i've made regex based on question.